# virtualenv on Windows10 gives error:The path python3 does not exist

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying the tutorial [Using Cloud Datastore with Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore), but when I run:

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

I got an error:

```
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
```

I checked the python version by running:

```
python -V
```

It gives me:

```
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)
```

I run `set python` to see the Environment variables, which gives me:

```
Environment variable python not defined
```

An annoying thing is that, this is a lab machine which I don't have the admin right, I need to email the IT Admin to change the Environment variables.

Tried:`virtualenv -p python env`

It gives me:

```
The path python (from --python=python) does not exist
```

Seems there is no way around until the environment variable is fixed.

Comment: Do you have python3 as an enviroment variable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reading this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup), I found the workaround for my case:

```
virtualenv --python "C:\\Anaconda3\\python.exe" env
```

Comment: I found the path on my system from the Anaconda Prompt by running `where python`; it showed me the path within my user folder, as I hadn't installed Anaconda system-wide.

Answer (score 9):

If `python --V` is showing a version greater than 3, then why not try:

```
virtualenv -p python env
```

instead? The value of the `p` flag is simply referring to the version of python you're wanting to create the virtual environment with. In this case, `python` is greater than version 3.

Comment: Thanks This one worked for me after the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this: **virtualenv --python "*Your python.exe path*" '*Name of your virtual folder*'**. You can take your python.exe path from your environment variables which is in properties of your '*This PC*' or '*My Computer*'.

Then get into the folder and run the command: ***.\Scripts\activate***

Enter the command pip freeze to make sure you have created your virtual environment successfully! It should return nothing since it is like an empty basket. Look at[image] how it comes in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:  On my Win10, for python3 scripts, I run py c:\path\to\script.
For example:

```
py -m pip --version
```

So to make the above command work, I used:

```
py -m venv env
```

and:

```
virtualenv -p py env
```

So that could be a possible solution as well.