# "The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist" error

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have added `python36/Scripts` in the environment variable's path file and python36 as well is added. But it still shows the following error

Command = `C:\Users\Sonalika\dev\trydjango1-11>virtualenv -p python3`

Error I receive:

> The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist

Comment: HI Sonalika, people will downvote your question if you didn't edit it, because it dosen't match the website questions quality : )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv on Windows10 gives error:The path python3 does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138803/virtualenv-on-windows10-gives-errorthe-path-python3-does-not-exist)

Comment: hi can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726288/apache-airflow-installing-method-failed

Answer (score 24):

try something like this, here C:/Python36/python.exe give the full address of python3 executable

```
virtualenv env -p C:/Python36/python.exe
```

Comment: If you already have python3 in your PATH try 
`virtualenv  -p python3.exe ENV`

Comment: I had Python3.7 installed in my system but the executable file was `python.exe`.
So, this worked for me - 
`virtualenv -p python.exe ENV`

Comment: hi can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726288/apache-airflow-installing-method-failed

Answer (score 7):

Using full path will address this issue.

```
$  virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 testenvironment
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/nansari/testenvironment/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/nansari/testenvironment/bin/python (you must use /home/nansari/testenvironment/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$  which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$  python --version
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$
```

Comment: You may need to add "sudo -H" in front... but it works... if you want to install a different version of Python you first need to know where it is by typing "where Pythonxxx" on Mac (which on Microsoft)

Comment: This worked for me thanks (macOS Catalina with python and python3.)

Answer (score 2):

if you have already python in you PATH, sure it works by default with python, no python3.
you just have to `run virtualenv -p python env`

Comment: hi can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726288/apache-airflow-installing-method-failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
python -m easy_install virtualenv
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code or commands. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command virtualenv -p python env
i.e without specifying python3, i had same problem while using pycharm and after running this command on the terminal the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your Command Prompt window, make sure to select "Run as administrator"