# Apache Airflow installing method failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm a MEAN STACK Developer. I have a new task like I have to monitor a folder If any file has created/updated/deleted in that. I need to monitor the folder and do some calculation and then I pushed the result into SQL.

so that I came to Apache Airflow.

I'm new to apache airflow and I don't have any knowledge in python also.
I have [read](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2017/03/19/developing-workflows-with-apache-airflow/) this article for apache airflow.

so I have created the folder and went inside and trying to run this code

while running this code

> `` virtualenv -p `which python3` venv ``

I am getting this error.

`The path which (from --python=which) does not exist.`

can anyone help me

Comment: This question has nothing to do with airflow. Also, this line works for me, but it could whatever. Please try this instead: `virtualenv -p python3 venv`.

Comment: Hi @bosnjak I have created the python3 file as txt. and I try to run your command it shows  `The path python3 (from --python=python3) is not an executable file` this error

Comment: What are you trying to do? Creating `python3` as a file doesn't make any sense. The `--python` instructs the virtual env which python interpreter to use, why would you create a txt file? I would urge you to read `virtualenv` documentation and understand what it does before trying things randomly. If I've missed your point, do let me know.